# Show Jquery Progress bar in ajaxStart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AjaxFileupload for uploading Large File, I am following [This link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/async-file-upload-jquery-and)
I have to show jquery Progress bar on start of Ajax call and Hide/change its text on finish of Ajax call,How can I show Progress Bar on ajaxstart?
I tried this but its not working

```
  $("#progressbar").ajaxStart(function () {
                // $(this).show();
                $(this).progressbar("value", 10);
            }).ajaxComplete(function () {
                //$(this).hide();
                $(this).progressbar("value", 100);
            });
//ajax call


<div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">          
    </div>
```

Comment: Any error you might want to share? Did you check the console?

Comment: No Error in console, I tried putting debugger on this code,but its not hitting it

Comment: so whats 'progressbar' then?

Comment: i always feel joyful as butterflies when i see questions ending with "but it is not working". What exactly is not working? does progress bar even show up? use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), it is awesome

Comment: wich JQuery version are you using?

Comment: Yes Progress bar not showing,

Comment: Jquery version is 2.1.1 and jquery ui is 1.11.0

Comment: why $(this).show() it's commented?

Comment: No luck, I am trying by changing jquery version